# How to join query with calculate in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to join query with calculate in mysql?

fab_in table
[image]

fab_out table

[image]

my query below

```
  SELECT fabric_in.fabric_id, fabric_in.fabric_date, fabric_in.fabric_order_qty, fabric_in.fabric_rejected_qty, fabric_in.fabric_rejected_reason, fabric_in.fabric_total_qty, fabric_in.fabric_company_name, fabric_out.fabric_out_qty 
    FROM fabric_out 
    RIGHT JOIN fabric_in 
ON fabric_out.fabric_id=fabric_in.fabric_id
```

Result query 
[image]

but i want sum relation with fabric_id can you any help pls
[image]

Comment: Use SUM(fabric_out_qty) function of MySQL group by fabric_id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    fabric_in.fabric_id, 
    fabric_in.fabric_date, 
    fabric_in.fabric_order_qty, 
    fabric_in.fabric_rejected_qty, 
    fabric_in.fabric_rejected_reason, 
    fabric_in.fabric_total_qty, 
    fabric_in.fabric_company_name, 
    SUM(fabric_out.fabric_out_qty) AS fabric_out_qty
FROM fabric_out 
RIGHT JOIN fabric_in 
ON fabric_out.fabric_id=fabric_in.fabric_id
GROUP BY fabric_in.fabric_id
```

Comment: Thank you jazdanow

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the aggregate functions of MySQL:

```
SELECT MAX(fabric_in.fabric_id) as fabric_id, 
       MAX(fabric_in.fabric_date) as fabric_date, 
       MAX(fabric_in.fabric_order_qty) as fabric_order_qty, 
       MAX(fabric_in.fabric_rejected_qty) as fabric_rejected_qty, 
       MAX(fabric_in.fabric_rejected_reason) as fabric_rejected_reason, 
       MAX(fabric_in.fabric_total_qty) as fabric_total_qty, 
       MAX(fabric_in.fabric_company_name) as fabric_company_name, 
       SUM(fabric_out.fabric_out_qty) AS fabric_out_qty
    FROM fabric_out 
    RIGHT JOIN fabric_in 
    ON fabric_out.fabric_id=fabric_in.fabric_id
    GROUP BY fabric_in.fabric_id
```

This schould work for you, not tested.

Answer (score 0):

as new version you need to add all column as group by or aggravate function. so you can use your query this way.

```
    SELECT fabric_in.fabric_id,fabric_in.fabric_date, 
    fabric_in.fabric_order_qty, fabric_in.fabric_rejected_qty,
    fabric_in.fabric_rejected_reason, fabric_in.fabric_total_qty,
    fabric_in.fabric_company_name,a.fabric_out_qty 
        FROM fabric_in 
        RIGHT JOIN  (select fabric_id,sum(fabric_out_qty) as total from 
    fabric_out group by fabric_id ) as a
    ON a.fabric_id=fabric_in.fabric_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT 
    fabric_in.fabric_id,
    fabric_in.fabric_date, 
    fabric_in.fabric_order_qty, 
    fabric_in.fabric_rejected_qty,
    fabric_in.fabric_total_qty,
    fabric_in.fabric_company_name,
    a.fabric_out_qty 
FROM fabric_in RIGHT JOIN  
    (select sum(fabric_out_qty) as out_total FROM fabric_out group by fabric_id ) as a ON a.fabric_id=fabric_in.fabric_id;
```